# Can someone explain the fft of real data

Tags: fft

Hopefully someone can help explain this to me as I am getting very confused trawling through google.

I would like to know the exact steps to perform the FFT and IFFT of a set of real data samples, all the examples I found are either start with complex values or don't explain the exact steps without bringing huge amounts of mathematics into the process.

I am after a simple bullet point list of what to do, is that too much to ask for.

Cheers

Comment: I would also like a simple bulleted list to building a small nuclear reactor, without going into physics, math, etc.  I just need part list and a simple construction algorithm, preferably in less then 20 steps.

Answer (score 0):

A Fast Fourier Transform(FFT) is an algorithm that efficiently computes the [Discrete Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).

There are several FFT algorithms so the exact steps to be followed will depend on the particular FFT algorithm you are looking to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the response. what are the names of the common implementations for real data? maybe I can do some research on them.